# Read text file line by line in c++ with each line being of different data types?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

The question is as follows:
Given a data file (text file) named inFile.txt with the contents:

```
2 6 -6 -13 78 34 -1 
2.1 5.6 -8.13 
'A' 'B' 'B' 'A'
```

Read this file into your C++ program called sums.cpp which calculates first the sum of the integers, then the sum of the floating point numbers (data type double) and finally concatenate the characters to the string "ABBA". The output of the sums.cpp should be stored in the output file outFile.txt.

I have managed to extract each line of the file in a string.But I have no idea how to proceed with these strings and sum their values into three different data type variables.
This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream fin("inFile.txt");
    ofstream fout("outFile.txt");
    while (!fin.eof()) {

        char line[100];

        while (fin.getline(line, 100)) {

            int i = 0;
            int sumi = 0;
            if ((isdigit(line[i])) && (line[i + 1] == ' ')) {
                int l = strlen(line);
                cout << line << endl;
                for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    if (isdigit(line[i]) && (line[i + 2] != '-'))
                        sumi += (int)line[i];
                    else if (isdigit(line[i]) && (line[i + 2] == '-'))
```

Comment: I'd look at the first character of each string and then work out the conversion mechanism from that ...

Comment: You can see if it's a number by its digits and an int if there is no period

Comment: You may classify the input strings: If it contains `-`, digits and `.`, it could be a floating point number (consider as `double`) else if it contains `-` and digits it could be an integer (consider as `int`)  else consider it as characters only.

Comment: The problem as stated only requires you to process that particular file, not anything more general.

Comment: I suspect that you learned about `std::istringstream` not long ago.

Comment: You should include code pasted as text, not an image.

Comment: Note that each line is **exactly the same data type**: a character sequence. The question is about how to **convert** a character sequence into various types. Keep that conversion in mind; conflating it with reading the character sequence muddles the process and makes things confusing.

Answer (score 3):

### Assuming Fixed File Layout

Using some c++14 goodness:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/345b17fb7555a4eb)</kbd>**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
T sum_line(std::string const& line) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    return std::accumulate(std::istream_iterator<T>(iss), {}, T{});
}

template <>
std::string sum_line<std::string>(std::string const& line) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::string accum, v;
    while (iss >> std::quoted(v, '\''))
        accum += v;

    return accum;
}

int main() {
    std::string line;
    if (getline(std::cin, line)) std::cout << "First line: " << sum_line<int>(line) << "\n";
    if (getline(std::cin, line)) std::cout << "Second line: " << sum_line<double>(line) << "\n";
    if (getline(std::cin, line)) std::cout << "Third line: " << sum_line<std::string>(line) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
First line: 100
Second line: -0.43
Third line: ABBA
```

### Detecting Per Line Data Type

This calls for a proper parser function. Let's use Boost Spirit instead of rolling our own:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5c70021ef982798)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>
#include <numeric>

namespace {
    static auto LineParser() {
        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

        return copy(skip(blank) [
                hold[
                     *lexeme["'" >> *~char_("'") >> "'"] >> eoi
                   | *int_ >> eoi
                   | *double_ >> eoi
                ]
            ]);
    }

    template <typename... T> using VVector = boost::variant<std::vector<T>...>;
    using LineData = VVector<std::string, int, double>;

    LineData ParseLine(std::string const& line) {
        LineData data;
        boost::spirit::qi::parse(line.begin(), line.end(), LineParser(), data);
        return data;
    }
}

struct Processor {
    using result_type = std::string;

    template <typename... T> 
    auto operator()(boost::variant<T...> const& v) const {
        return boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
    }

    template <typename T> auto operator()(std::vector<T> const& v) const {
        return std::to_string(std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), T{}));
    }
    auto operator()(std::vector<std::string> const& v) const {
        return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), std::string{});
    }
};

int main() {
    Processor const process;
    int linenum = 0;

    for (std::string line; getline(std::cin, line);) {
        std::cout << "Processed line #" << ++linenum << ": " << process(ParseLine(line)) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Given an input of

```
'A'
2 6 -6 -13 78 34 -1 

'A' 'B' 'B' 'A'
2.1 5.6 -8.13
```

That prints

```
Processed line #1: A
Processed line #2: 100
Processed line #3: 
Processed line #4: ABBA
Processed line #5: -0.430000
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answering my question @sehe . But as you can see, I am a beginner in C++ and it is required that I solve this question using only the libraries that I have included in my won code. I do not understand the various new libraries that you used. I may only use the following libraries: iostream, fstream, cstring, and string. Thankyou!